# Apache SSI not work for image as link separate

Tags: apache, web, ssi

On the website the following code for check - a call from the homepage of the website is used or not:

```
<!--#if expr="$DOCUMENT_URI=/^\/index.shtml/" -->
<img...>
<!--#else -->
<a href="/index.shtml"><img...</a>
<!--#endif -->
```

The code works at Apache 2.2 without failure, but on Apache 2.4 and is newer gives an error message [an error occurred while processing this directive]!

Prompt how it is correct to correct a code for operation on any versions of Apache?

Comment: First you are missing a `<` at the beginning

Comment: only this place - code on site is correct

Answer (score 0):

The #if expr element now uses the new *expression parser*. Something like this but not tested :

```
<If "%{DOCUMENT_URI} == m#^/index.shtml$#">
    <img...>
<Else>
    <a href="/index.shtml"><img...</a>
</If>
```

1. Let's see *expression parser* documentation here : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/expr.html
2. An aleternative is to reactivate the old syntax with the new directive `SSILegacyExprParser` in your conf.

Note: mod_include needs to be activated with :

```
sudo a2enmod include
```

Comment: "#if expr element now uses the new expression parser" - what about cross version code for old and new Apache without SSILegacyExprParser?

Comment: I add an example of the new syntax now.

Comment: Is it ok @lyalin-mikhail ?

Comment: So please vote for the answer if you agree with it ;-)